# CSS add pointer style only if a div has text

Tags: html, css

In the following situation, how can add `cursor:pointer` to only the second div which contains the text `Cursor pointer required here`.

The `div` with `class="x95qze"` remains the same. The `div` or `text` within it is added/removed using javascript.

`cursor:pointer` is required only when there is plain text inside `div class="x95qze`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Cursor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="x95qze">
        <div class="RiYDI">No cursor pointer required here</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="x95qze">Cursor pointer required here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .x95qze {
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:5px;
    }
    
    .x95qze .RiYDI {
        border:1px solid black;
        width:50%
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

`<div class="x95qze"><span id="js-output">Cursor pointer required here.</span></div>`

CSS

```
#js-output {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the text you can use pure javascript `includes`

**First find the text**

```
const sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

const word = 'fox';

console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.includes(word) ? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
// expected output: "The word "fox" is in the sentence"

if (sentence.includes(word)) {
   let element = document.querySelector('.x95qze);
   element.setAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer;");

}
```

more info [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a text selector called `:contains(text)`.
After updating content, i call a function which iterates over `.x95qze` classed tags and adds `cursored` class to tags those has no children.

And in css for `cursored` class I add a rule of `cursor:pointer`.

```js
function checkCursors(){
  $('.x95qze:contains(Cursor)').each(function(i, container) {
      $(container).toggleClass('cursored',   $(container).children().length == 0);
   });
}
// After content updated
checkCursors();
```

```css
.x95qze.cursored { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Cursor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="x95qze">
        <div class="RiYDI">No cursor pointer required here</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="x95qze">Cursor pointer required here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```